# Select2 multi select dropdown causing window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have a multi select dropdown with select2 plugin. When the dropdown is open, user scrolls the window and click somewhere the click event is not getting triggered. Instead the windows scrolls automatically and focuses on the dropdown.

Please find the demo here. In the example scrolldown and open the select box, keep the select box opened, scroll top and click on Content 1

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/axvv87fr/4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#multiselectDropdown").select2()
  $("h1").on("click", function() {
    alert("clicked " + $(this).text())
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  Content1
</h1>
<h1>
  Content2
</h1>
<h1>
  Content3
</h1>
<h1>
  Content4
</h1>
<h1>
  Content5
</h1>
<h1>
  Content6
</h1>
<h1>
  Content7
</h1>
<h1>
  Content8
</h1>
<h1>
  Content9
</h1>
<h1>
  Content10
</h1>
<select id="multiselectDropdown" style="width:200px" multiple>

        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>

        </select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a plugin problem , as you can see in their github repository issues:

[closing dropdown which is out of the viewport causes viewport to scroll #3663](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3663)

and

[Scroll back to the input field when lost focus (after select2:closing) #4983](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4983#issuecomment-331560917)

User zoka123 mentioned that this problem can be solved by commenting out 
this part in **select2/dist/js/select2.full.js:**

```
line 1407 self.$selection.focus();
```

This issues is still open , and last activity was on 29 Dec 2017. So your best bet is to comment out this line of code for now and see if it will fix your problem.

Comment: this worked! thanks! Note: I created a copy of the original Select2.Min.JS just for the page that uses the multi-select... to avoid issues in other places with Select2.

Answer (score -1):

If you still encountered this problem, how I fixed the issue was via css.

```
.select2-dropdown .select2-results__option {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue.